# Trying to Understand AWS Cognito Login for iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've recently tried creating a basic app that allows for user sign-in/sign up. After looking around, I've decided I would like to try and integrate my app with AWS's services. I've tried reading the documentation and examples/forums; however, I cannot seem to wrap my head around the full process. It looks like in the `AppDelegate`, you set up the User Pool & extend the `AWSCognitoIdentityInteractiveAuthenticationDelegate` and declare a set of functions that set the `UI` based on a condition. I have been able to successfully sign up and confirm users, but I cannot understand the login/session process.
 Right now, on my main view, I call this:

```
let pool = AppDelegate.defaultUserPool()
let currUser = pool.currentUser()
if(currUser == nil) {
    pool.currentUser()?.getSession()
} else {
    print("user is logged in")
}
```

How I understand it is that, if a set of tokens are cached when you `call.currentUser()` it will return a value; however, if it is nil, you `call getSession()` which will start the login `UI/process` (because no values are cached). I have tried creating a sample app with `AWS Mobile Hub`, but even then, I get lost trying to follow along. Most of the documentation is in `Objective-C`, which I've tried translating to Swift, but still - I cannot understand. I would appreciate if someone could please help me understand this login process/flow. Also, if possible, I would appreciate any tips (or links to resources) on how to code a basic handler for if the user is/isn't signed in & how to properly sign them in.

Additional:
My login controller looks as follows:

```
...

@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let validFields = validateFields()
    if(validFields == "") {
        let username = usernameField.text!
        let password = passwordField.text!
        let authDetails = AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails(username: username, password: password)
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion?.set(result: authDetails)
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
}

// --- Functions to handle user login ---
func validateFields() -> String {
    var error = ""

    if (usernameField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        error = error + "- Please enter a valid username\n"
    }
    if (passwordField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        error = error + "- Please enter a valid password\n"
    }

    return error

}
// --- End functions to handle user login ---

}

extension LoginController: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {

//If username text is empty, set last known username as this value
public func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>) {
    self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (self.usernameText == nil) {
            self.usernameText = authenticationInput.lastKnownUsername
        }
    }
}

public func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: error.userInfo["__type"] as? String,
                                                    message: error.userInfo["message"] as? String,
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            let retryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(retryAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
        } else {
            //self.usernameField.text = nil
            print("User successfully logged in")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried looking at AWS Mobile Hub?  It makes adding login a lot easier.  Here is the page in the docs talking about how to add login:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html.  You should also look at the "Get Started" page as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that documentation is useless if you want to implement your own custom signin/signup UI. AWSAuthUIConfiguration offers only a few little customizations like changing background color etc

Comment: @KevinR I recently saw it & see it has significantly simplified since I last used it (used to be a whole Xcode project you would download). Sadly, I saw this after I had spent hours & hours trying to implement each service by itself haha. Luckily, I've got enough progress now that the app works as it should - still wish I could find a reference to ensure everything was implemented correctly

Comment: The AWSMobileHub Sample App uses the SDK and is a simple app that would demonstrate the features. You could check its implementation.